# Rendering an Action Template from another controller in Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm trying to render **replies/new** view in **post/show** view. When i tried

```
render "replies/new"
```

It shows me error as it seems it's looking for

```
replies/_new.html.erb
```

it worked when i used

```
render template: "replies/new"
```

But looks like it does not activate new action in replies controller so it doesn't create new reply. I could add something like **@reply = Reply.new** in **Post show** action but i assume there must be some more DRY way to solve it.

Comment: Where did you place `render 'replies/new'?` In the template or on controller action?

Comment: Another way of doing this is passing the new reply object as a partial local. Like:
`<%= render partial: 'replies/new', locals: {reply: Reply.new} %>`

Comment: In the template @JagdeepSingh

Comment: Then that's the expected behavior. Rails will consider it a partial name and search for _\_new.html/erb_.

Comment: Please show more of your controller and view (_show_) code to let us help you better.

Comment: @JagdeepSingh Thanks for help but solution is already below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> But looks like it does not activate new action in replies controller
>   so it doesn't create new reply

Reason: - Render doesn't create a new HTTP request(render does not load any context associated with a controller action. So, it will render the template),You may have lots of code in that new action but none of it will be run. ONLY THE VIEW WILL BE RENDERED.

You can try this

In `posts#show`

```
def show
  #foo = bar
  render "replies/new", locals: {reply: Reply.new}
end
```

In this way you would have to use local variables in `replies#new` too

```
def new
  #foo = bar
  reply = Reply.new
  render locals: {reply: reply}
end
```

In `replies/new.html.erb` use `reply` instead of `@reply`

Comment: Thanks. This make sense now. But it seems like adding **@reply = Reply.new** to **posts#show** is much less code. What do You think about this solution?

Comment: @J.Krzus Yes, you can do that too. :D